# MVVM Light - how to add (dynamic) usercontrol to the grid?

Tags: c#, uwp, user-controls, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to figure out how to add UserControl to the Grid depending on the user's choice.

*Short description:*

I have ComboBox:

- `ItemSource` binded to `ObservableCollection<Products>`,
- `SelectedItem` binded to `Product`.
- Inside the `MainPage.xaml` I have `<Grid>`

I have products like: `Doors`, `Lamps`, `Chairs` etc... All of them inherit from Product class.

*Looking for a hints/solutions:*

I have many UserControls with ViewModels for `Products`: One for `Doors`, one for `Lamps`, one for `Chairs`.

Depending on user choice I would like to add selected product UserControl to the `<Grid>`

*Example:*

- User selects "Chairs" from the Combobox, another ChairsUserControl.xaml will be added to the `<Grid>`
- User selects "Doors" from the Combobox, another DoorsUserControl.xaml will be added to the `<Grid>`

and so on... Grid may have many same UserControls (they can repeat).

many thanks for **any** hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: DataTemplateSelector